# Nested rows using STRUCT are not supported in Dataflow SQL (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-dataflow

With Dataflow SQL I would like to read a Pub/Sub topic, enrich the message and write the message to a Pub/Sub topic.

Which Dataflow SQL query will create my desired output message?

Pub/Sub **input** message:  {"event_timestamp":1619784049000, "device":{"ID":"some_id"}}

Desired Pub/Sub **output** message:  {"event_timestamp":1619784049000, "device":{“ID":"some_id", **“NAME”:”some_name”**}}

What I get is:  {"event_timestamp":1619784049000, "device":{"ID":"some_id"}, "NAME":"some_name" }

but I need the NAME **inside** the “device” attribute.

```
SELECT message_table.device as device, devices.name as NAME 
FROM pubsub.topic.project_id.`topic` as message_table
  JOIN bigquery.table.project_id.dataflow_sql_dataset.devices as devices 
  ON devices.device_id = message_table.device.id
```

Comment: Can you join a BQ table with your Dataflow SQL pipeline? like a simple query in fact.

Comment: yes i can. Like: SELECT message_table.device as device, "some_name" as NAME FROM pubsub.topic.project_id.topic as message_table JOIN bigquery.table.`project_id`.dataflow_sql_dataset.devices as devices ON devices.device_id = message_table.device.id

Comment: And, is it what you want to achieve? Else, I didn't understand yoru blocking point

Comment: what I get:  {"event_timestamp":1619784049000, "device":{"ID":"some_id"}, "NAME":"some_name" }

Comment: what is want:  {"event_timestamp":1619784049000, "device":{"ID":"some_id", "NAME":"some_name" }}.

Comment: I want "NAME" to be an attribute of "device".

Comment: Ok, your Dataflow SQL output is a PubSub, not a BigQuery, correct? Can you share your request?

Comment: My Dataflow SQL output is PubSub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Dataflow SQL does not currently support STRUCT/Sub queries, but we are working on it. Since there are some Apache Beam dependencies preventing its progress ([Nested Rows Support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9378), [Upgrading Calcite](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9379)), we cannot provide an ETA at the moment, but you can follow its progress on this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/190024082).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a struct in the projection (SELECT part)

```
SELECT STRUCT(message_table.device.ID as ID , devices.name as NAME) as device
FROM pubsub.topic.project_id.`topic` as message_table
  JOIN bigquery.table.project_id.dataflow_sql_dataset.devices as devices 
  ON devices.device_id = message_table.device.id
```

Comment: Thank you, guillaume. I tried it but during creation of the Dataflow Job  it gives an error: "exec.go:64","message":"Invalid/unsupported arguments for SQL job launch: Query uses unsupported SQL features: Does not support expr node kind RESOLVED_MAKE_STRUCT"}

Comment: My bad, I was sure it will work because it worked in SQL... Maybe a day my answer will be valid! But not today. I fear that there isn't solution for this case...

Comment: Thanks for you help, I appreciate it!