# How to output nested Row from Beam SQL (SqlTransform)?

Tags: apache-beam, beam-sql

I want to have Row with nested Row from output of Beam SQL (SqlTransform), but failing.

Questions:

1. What is the proper way to output Row with nested Row from SqlTransform? (Row type is described in [the docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/calcite/data-types/), so I believe it's supported)
2. If this is a bug/missing feature, is the problem of Beam itself? Or runner-dependent? (I'm currently using on DirectRunner, but going to use DataflowRunner in future.)

Version info:

- OS: macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina)
- Java: 11.0.11 (AdoptOpenJDK)
- Beam SDK: 2.32.0

Here's what I've tried, with no luck.

##### With Calcite dialect

```sql
SELECT ROW(foo, bar) as my_nested_row FROM PCOLLECTION
```

I was expecting this outputs row with following schema

```
Field{name=my_nested_row, description=, type=ROW<foo STRING NOT NULL, bar INT64 NOT NULL> NOT NULL, options={{}}}
```

but actually row is split into scalar fields like

```
Field{name=my_nested_row$$0, description=, type=STRING NOT NULL, options={{}}}
Field{name=my_nested_row$$1, description=, type=INT64 NOT NULL, options={{}}}
```

##### Zeta SQL

```sql
SELECT STRUCT(foo, bar) as my_nested_row FROM PCOLLECTION
```

I got an error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Does not support expr node kind RESOLVED_MAKE_STRUCT
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.translation.ExpressionConverter.convertRexNodeFromResolvedExpr (ExpressionConverter.java:363)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.translation.ExpressionConverter.convertRexNodeFromResolvedExpr (ExpressionConverter.java:323)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.translation.ExpressionConverter.convertRexNodeFromComputedColumnWithFieldList (ExpressionConverter.java:375)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.translation.ExpressionConverter.retrieveRexNode (ExpressionConverter.java:203)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.translation.ProjectScanConverter.convert (ProjectScanConverter.java:45)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.translation.ProjectScanConverter.convert (ProjectScanConverter.java:29)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.translation.QueryStatementConverter.convertNode (QueryStatementConverter.java:102)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.translation.QueryStatementConverter.convert (QueryStatementConverter.java:89)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.translation.QueryStatementConverter.convertRootQuery (QueryStatementConverter.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.ZetaSQLPlannerImpl.rel (ZetaSQLPlannerImpl.java:98)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.ZetaSQLQueryPlanner.convertToBeamRelInternal (ZetaSQLQueryPlanner.java:197)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.zetasql.ZetaSQLQueryPlanner.convertToBeamRel (ZetaSQLQueryPlanner.java:185)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.impl.BeamSqlEnv.parseQuery (BeamSqlEnv.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.expand (SqlTransform.java:171)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform.expand (SqlTransform.java:109)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal (Pipeline.java:548)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform (Pipeline.java:482)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply (PCollection.java:363)
    at dev.tmshn.playbeam.Main.main (Main.java:29)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Beam SQL does not yet support nested rows, mainly due to a lack of support in Calcite (and therefore a corresponding lack of support for the ZetaSQL implementation). See this [similar question focused on Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431641/nested-rows-using-struct-are-not-supported-in-dataflow-sql-gcp).

On the bright side, the [Jira issue tracking this support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-9378) seems to be resolved for 2.34.0, so proper support is likely upcoming.

Comment: Thank you for the Jira link! And it seems to be marked as resolved at the beginning of this September. Looking forward to v2.34 release.